# Using CSS Animations to cause a background of a div to have a flickering light effect

Tags: html, css, animation

Ok I'm helping my brother build a website and his main image in the background is a piece that he worked on. We want the image to transition to another PNG and go back and forth to emulate a flicking candle set.

I'm really new to CSS animations and my first attempt was to load the base image as the default background for the header DIV and use the overlay image to do the animation but that caused issues with the text and other information on top of the DIV.

So ideally I'd like to have both images as backgrounds on the DIV and have it slowly transition from 0% opacity to 100% opacity and alternate. I'm perfectly ok with a solution that only works IE 10 and up.

Here is the CSS attempt

```
header{
    background: url(../images/header_bg_1.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.section_overlay {
    -webkit-animation-name: example; 
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; 
    animation-name: animateheader;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animateheader{
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes animateheader{
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@-o-keyframes animateheader{
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes animateheader{
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

Here is the HTML Piece

```
    <header id="HOME" style="background-position: 50% 50px;">
              <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
                <div class="container">
                  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                  <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" alt=""></a>
                  </div>

                  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                      <li><a href="#HOME">Home</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#SERVICE">Services</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#ABOUT">About</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#TESTIMONIAL">Testimonial</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#WORK">Work</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#CONTACT">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                </div><!-- /.container -->
              </nav> 
          <div class="section_overlay">
              <div class="container">
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                          <div class="home_text wow fadeInUp animated">
                              <h2>it’s MrCreeep</h2>
                              <p>Tag Line would go Here</p>
                              <img src="images/shape.png" alt="">                        
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>          
          </div>          
    </header>
```

Here is two direct links to the Images. The first should transition to the second and then back again and if you can offer up any help to make it look more dynamic and flickering instead of just a standard fade in and fade out I would appreciate it greatly.

http://mrcreeep.com/images/header_bg_1.png
http://mrcreeep.com/images/header_bg_2.png

Comment: Where is the second image link in code?

Comment: Also could you post your whole code? or better provide just link if you have it live. At least provide whole css for header.

Comment: As to your comment "more dynamic and flickering": are you looking for a pure CSS solution (which I'm not sure would be the solution, though I'm no CSS master), or a JS/jQuery solution? Are you hoping the opacity will be random-ish?

Comment: I am willing to use JS/jQuery but I was looking for a purely CSS/CSS3 solution if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the second image as a `background-image` to the `.section-overlay`:

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/1o1m44n5/2/)

Something like:

```
header {
    background: url('http://mrcreeep.com/images/header_bg_1.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
}
.section_overlay {
    height: 100%;
    background: url('http://mrcreeep.com/images/header_bg_2.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-animation-name: example;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-name: animateheader;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

And to make it look like its flickering, you can speed up the animation duration and add some random opacity changes:

```
@-webkit-keyframes animateheader {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    30% {
       opacity: .3;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes animateheader {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    30% {
       opacity: .3;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes animateheader {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    30% {
       opacity: .3;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@keyframes animateheader {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    30% {
       opacity: .3;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

This is just a quick example, but you can add more random opacity changes and increase the animation duration for different/less repetitive effects.

Comment: Wow that works really well and I think if I play with adding more opacity changes as you have already done it should turn out just like we're wanting. 

Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your **text gets messed up is positions of content** inside header. So here i am posting the answer with **my own custom sipmle code** along specifying what all you need to **keep in mind**

Your header structure must be as:

1) Your **header** element with image_1 as background, **must have specified height & `z-index:1`.**

2) `<span class="section_overlay"></span>` Next your **.section_overlay** class with `span` so won't break line. It must have **`position:absolute, display:block; background:image_2`**.

3) Now that you have image overlay on header, you need to wrap all your code lines(`HTML Elements`) wrapped in a `div`. So directly giving **`z-index:9999;`**(9999 - Safe side) to that div.

**Solution**

```css
body
{
width:100%;
margin:0px;
}

header
{
margin:20px 0%;
top:0%;
left:0%;
width:100%;
height:350px;
background:url(http://i.imgur.com/PgqCVJQ.png);
background-size:cover;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
overflow:hidden;
z-index:1;
}

.overlay
{
position:absolute;
display:block;
height:100%;
width:100%;
background:url(http://i.imgur.com/jS0YhNP.png);
background-size:cover;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
-webkit-animation: flickerAnimation 1s infinite;
-moz-animation: flickerAnimation 1s infinite;
-o-animation: flickerAnimation 1s infinite;
animation: flickerAnimation 1s infinite;
}

header > div
{
position:relative;
z-index:999;
}

.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #444;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.nav li {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
}
 
.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  transition: .3s background-color;
}
 
.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #005f5f;
}
 
.nav a.active {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
  cursor: default;
}
 
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .nav li {
    width: 120px;
    border-bottom: none;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
  }
 
  /* Option 1 - Display Inline */
  .nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
  }
 
  /* Options 2 - Float
  .nav li {
    float: left;
  }
  .nav ul {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .nav {
    background-color: #444;
  }
  */
}

@keyframes flickerAnimation {
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-o-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
```

```html
<header>
 <span class="overlay"></span>
  <div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li class="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="tutorials"><a class="active" href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
        <li class="about"><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="news"><a href="#">Newsletter</a></li>
        <li class="contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</header>
```

The below demo is using your HTML code, have a look at it **would be easy to understand**.

[JSFiddle:DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nwafmsy1/)